# Using javascript to include tables in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I want to use javascript to create some color picker in a html page.

Until now I was using `.hide/.show` but I think is better to create only the tables that I need, right?

Also I have the tables in another html file, so I use the `{% include %}` TAG but I don't need to.

My `html` template:

```
...
<div id='color_table'>
</div>
...
```

My `script-jquery.js`:

```
  function show_color_tables(num, colors) {
    for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
      //var node = document.createTextNode("{% include 'banner/_colortable.html' with table='"+i+"' color='"+colors+"' %}");
      //document.getElementById('color_table').appendChild(node);
      //document.getElementById('color_table').innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
      //document.getElementById('color_table').firstChild.contentWindow.document.write("{% include 'banner/_colortable.html' with table='"+i+"' color='"+colors+"' %}");
      var node = "{% include 'banner/_colortable.html' with table='"+i+"' color='"+colors+"' %}";
      $('#color_table').html(node);
    };
  };
```

This writes on the screen:

```
{% include 'banner/_colortable.html' with table='0' color='Tutti' %}
```

but don't import the tables from `_colortable.html`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use Django template tags inside static files such as `.js` as they are directly served without preprocessing. You might try embedding the Javascript code inside your template

Comment: You can use Ajax to dynamically include HTML,.. If your already using jQuery it's as easy as doing `$('#color_table').load('banner/_colortable.html')`